# Classification of finite complex reflection groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, gr.group-theory

**Background:**

Let $K$ be a field and let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $K$-vector space. A *pseudoreflection* (or usually imprecisely just *reflection*) in $V$ is an element $1 \neq s \in \mathrm{GL}(V)$ fixing a hyperplane. A *reflection representation* of a group $W$ over $K$ is a $K$-linear representation $\rho:W \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}(V)$, such that $\rho(W)$ is generated by reflections. A group $W$ is called a *reflection group* over $K$ if it admits a reflection representation over $K$.

Shephard-Todd classified (see below) the finite irreducible reflection groups over $\mathbb{C}$ (i.e. those finite groups admitting an irreducible reflection representation over $\mathbb{C}$).

**Question:**

Is there also a classification of the finite irreducible reflection representations over $\mathbb{C}$?

Edit: This question is very imprecise as indicated in the comments below. I should say what "classification of representations" means, and I have to admit: I don't know. A few ideas in this direction are:

- determine the isomorphism classes of finite irreducible reflection representations over $\mathbb{C}$, where an *isomorphism* between two reflection representations $\rho:W \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}(V)$, $\rho':W' \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}(V')$ is a vector space isomorphism $f:V \rightarrow V'$ such that $f \rho(G) f^{-1} = \rho'(G)$. (I think the Shephard-Todd classification is a classification relative to this notion!?)
- the same as above but an isomorphism is a vector space isomorphism $f:V \rightarrow V'$ and a group isomorphism $\varphi:W \rightarrow W'$ such that $f \rho(g) f^{-1} = \rho'( \varphi(g) )$ for all $g \in W$.
- consider pairs $(W,T)$ consisting of a finite irreducible reflection group over $\mathbb{C}$ and a subset $T$ which are generating reflections of some irreducible reflection representation of $W$ and then determine isomorphism classes of such pairs.
- [Insert your idea here].

My motivation for this question is something like this: A Cherednik-Algebra is defined for any finite irreducible reflection representation over $\mathbb{C}$. In what sense does the algebra depend on the group alone and not on the choice of a particular reflection representation?

Comment: Your definition of isomorphism of representations is somewhat different from usual no?  Normally one would require an elementwise compatibility $f \rho(g) f^{-1}=\rho'(g)$ for all $g \in G$.

Comment: Good question. I don't know. I came across this definition in "Reflection groups and invariant theory" by Richard Kane (p. 156). But he's not really using this concept...

Comment: I don't have Kane's book to hand, but it seems likely to me that he introduces this definition in order to discuss the classification of subgroups of GL(V) up to conjugacy---which is really a different from classifying representations of a particular group up to isomorphism!  The latter is a finer (fewer elements in each equivalence class) classification, and more interesting/difficult.

Comment: The difference between these definitions is in outer automorphisms. Arminius identifies twists by outer automorphisms, while Stephen does not. Say, take the dihedral group with even edge: it has two standard reflection representations, different by outer twist. In Arminius' world they are the same and in Stephen's they are different.

Comment: Hiya Bugs, For W(B2) at least they are not different. The group of outer automorphisms may well fix rep'ns occasionally.

Comment: ..also, if we're identifying things up to automorphisms coming from GL(V), the question is much less interesting (and in fact, Arminius gave the answer in the text of the question).

Comment: ...though Shephard-Todd probably gets more credit for completing the classification than is really deserved.  Most of the work had been done, I believe, by the time that paper was written---especially for the classification of the primitive groups.

Comment: I just want to point out that the point of Shephard-Todd was not classification, rather it was the Chevalley-Shephard-Todd theorem. Since their proof is case-by-case, they listed complex reflection groups and so their paper became a convenient reference.

Comment: You're absolutely right!  That observation (that reflection groups are precisely those with polynomial invariants) really was important.

Comment: Hey, Steve! I think I have gone slightly bonkers with my comment: twisting by the outer automorphism does not change to reflection representation. I see it is true, in general: twist by a diagram automorphism is not changing the reflection representation of the Coxeter group.

Comment: Bugs: Interesting!  Is it obvious that should be so?  

Comment: Arminius: For non-faithful rep's $G$, T. Chmutova has written this paper: 

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0505653

I think she will have something to say about what you're interested in.

Comment: Steve: I think so. The reflection rep is determined by the diagram, diagram automorphism does not change the data that determines it.

Comment: I think that your definition of (pseudo-)reflection is non-standard, since it doesn't include the [usual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoreflection) finite-order condition.

Answer (score 3):

This was done by Shephard-Todd. A recent book on this is:

MR2542964 (Review)  Lehrer, Gustav I. ;  Taylor, Donald E.
Unitary reflection groups.
Australian Mathematical Society Lecture Series, 20.
Cambridge University Press, Cambridge,  2009. viii+294 pp. ISBN: 978-0-521-74989-3

Comment: Of course I did not look at their original work... :( Let's see.

Comment: Dear Bruce,

I'm still somewhat confused by the intent of the original question, but it matters whether one is classifying reflection representations of a group up to isomorphism, or just reflection subgroups of GL(V) up to conjugacy.  The former was definitely not done by Shephard-Todd.

Best,
Stephen

Answer (score 3):

Answering the first question, if the field has characteristic zero then the classification will be reduced to Shephard-Todd. By this I mean that every finite reflection group will be on Shephard-Todd list. In the opposite direction, finite Weyl groups will appear over every field and the rest of them will need some algebraic integers to be present in your field...

In positive characteristic, the life gets tough as pseudoreflections can be unipotent. I do not know whether classification is known but I can say that the list will get much longer...

Comment: The question was about $\CC$... but you're right, the list gets longer.  Here is one reference: MR0603578 (82i:20060) Zalesskiĭ, A. E.; Serežkin, V. N. Finite linear groups generated by reflections. (Russian) Izv. Akad. Nauk SSSR Ser. Mat. 44 (1980), no. 6, 1279--1307, 38.

Comment: ...and here is a paper which might be easier to get: 

http://www.springerlink.com.ezproxy.webfeat.lib.ed.ac.uk/content/v15174k6t232k105/

Comment: Your link brings me to UofEdinburgh site that asks me for some stupid password and my command of whiterussian is somewhat rusty but thanks for info, anyway!

Comment: BTW, the question is about $K$, not $\CC$, unless I missed something

Comment: Wassup Bugs, Sorry about the broken tex/link! The question (see above) is "Is there also a classification of the finite irreducible reflection representations over $\mathbb{C}$?" The OP began by defining refl. groups over a field K, but then switched the char. 0. The paper (which I have not found available free online) was "Determination of the finite primitive reflection groups over an arbitrary field of characteristic not 2". I. Geom. Dedicata 9 (1980), no. 2, 239--253 by A. Wagner. It's part of a three part series. 

Comment: Geez I'm having a hard time with tex in comments...

Comment: The link works fine (although it's still not free) if you strip out the 'proxy' part:  http://www.springerlink.com/content/v15174k6t232k105.

Comment: After Springer's re-organisation, the current [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29060/classification-of-finite-complex-reflection-groups#comment64059_29069) is [Wagner - Determination of the finite primitive reflection groups over an arbitrary field of characteristic not $2$ - I](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00147439).